# What do the numbers in Youtube Suggestion API mean?

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, youtube-javascript-api

Here is a portion of the response from Youtube Suggestion API for the URL (https://clients1.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&q=b%20walmart&gl=&jsonp=jsonpCB&_=1600401501454)

```
[
  "b walmart",
  [
    [
      "walmart b complex",
      0,
      [
        22,
        30
      ]
    ],
    [
      "b walmart",
      0
    ],
    [
      "walmart b&m",
      0,
      [
        22,
        30
      ]
    ]
  ],
  {
    "k": 1,
    "q": "295XbO_S8qtvvBAI-FdfMCmHaHk"
  }
]
```

Could someone help me understand the significance of the numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: what does the documentation for this `Youtube Suggestion API` say about the response

Comment: Sorry @Jaromanda X I have searched and have not been able to find helpful info about it.